# Проблема с виртуальным окружением (Пайчарм)

Tags: python, pycharm, venv

Создаю проект в Пайчарме и виртуальное окружение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Устанавливаю Джанго
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Создаю приложение startproject xxx
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Открываю это приложение через open

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу выбрать Виртуальное окружение, которые уже создано и где установлен Джанго
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А он не работает, просто ничего не происходит, в нижнем левом углу нет интерпретатора

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если есть замечания или советы можете, говорить и рассказывать.

Comment: «Открываю это приложение через open» — а надо открывать ту папку, в которой вы создали виртуальное окружение, раз уж вы почему-то решили сделать их разными папками

Answer (score 0):

В первую очередь стоит открыть папку всего проекта, в котором должно быть данное виртуальное окружение. Если ошибка продолжает проявляться, открой в проводнике папку проекта и удали оттуда папку `.idea`, затем удали папку `venv`, открой проект снова и повторно поставь виртуальное окружение.